# get result on search box

Tags: php

i created a search toolbar on my system i am working, but it does not execute what i am searching, it always return me no results even if the keyword i searched is found on my table in database. pls help me analyze my codes, where i am miss or wrong thnks in advance.
 heres my code. search.php

```
    <form method="post" action="search.php">
     <p><input type="text" name="keywords"><input type="submit" value="Search"></p>
       </form>
       <?php
       include 'connect/func.inc.php';
       if(isset($_POST['keywords'])){
       $suffix = '';
    //trim is for ignoring spaces on the input type text
    $keywords = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(trim($_POST['keywords'])));

    $errors = array();
    if(empty($keywords)){
        $errors[]='Please enter a search keyword';
        }
        else if (strlen($keywords)<0) { 
        //strlen is for the no. of char
        $errors[]='Please three or more characters';
        }else if (search_results($keywords) === false){
        $errors[]='Your search for '.$keywords.' returned no results';
        } 

        if (empty($errors)) {
        //search
        $results = search_results($keywords);
        $results_num = count($results);
        $suffix = ($results_num !=1) ? 's': '';
        echo '<p>Your search for<strong>'. $keywords.'</strong> returned <strong>'. $results_num .'</strong>result',$suffix, '</p>';
        foreach($results as $result) {
        echo '<p><strong>', $result['studId'], '</strong><br>', $result['fname'],  $result['mname'], $result['lname'],'</p>';

        }
            //print_r(search_results($keywords));
        } else {
            foreach($errors as $error) {
            echo $error, '</br>';
                                        }
        }
    }

   ?>
```

function.inc.php

```
<?php
include 'db.inc.php';
function search_results($keywords) {
    $returned_results = array();
    $where = "";

    $keywords = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $keywords);
    //preg_split select evry word and ignore many spaces
    $total_keywords = count($keywords);
    foreach($keywords as $key=>$keyword){

        $where .= "`keywords` LIKE '%$keyword%'";   
            if($key != ($total_keywords -1)) {
                $where .= " AND ";
            }
    }
    //echo $where;
        $results = "SELECT `studId`, LEFT(`fname`, 20) as `fname`, LEFT(`lname`, 20) as `lname`, LEFT(`mname`, 20) as `mname` FROM tbl_student WHERE $where";
    //echo $results;

    $results_num = ($results = mysql_query($results)) ? mysql_num_rows($results) : 0;
    if($results_num === 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
    //get info into database
        while ($results_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) { 
            $returned_results[] = array(
            'studId'=> $results_row['studId'], 
            'fname'=> $results_row['fname'], 
            'mname'=> $results_row['mname'], 
            'lname'=> $results_row['lname']);
            }
                return $returned_results;
        }
    }

?>
```

my table is like this. tbl_student

```
  studId    fname   mname   lname
  c-1111    peter   jan      yu
  c-1112    jane    trish    li
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: What are you inputting when it says no results?

Comment: @EM-Creations.. i type 'c-1111' but still it returns me no results

Comment: @EM-Creations. i think i know where im wrong.... it is on my $where .= "`keywords` LIKE '%$keyword%'"; i should suppose to change this, and i want to ask if it is possible to add more column names? how?

Comment: @EM-Creations. i am correct, and now i could have my results now...

Comment: @PotPot Check my answer, did that help at all?

Comment: @EM-Creations, yeah it help me, but what about to have more columns in my $where variable? how should i apply it? for a purpose that i would not only putting specific keyword rather studid but also the fname, mname, and lname..

Answer (score 0):

By the look of it you're referencing a column that doesn't exist. Where in your database structure is a column called "keywords"? I don't see it.

From your comment under your original question it seems like you should change

```
$where .= "`keywords` LIKE '%$keyword%'";
```

to

```
$where .= "`studId` LIKE '%$keyword%'";
```

Comment: @EM-Creations... yeah, i actually solve my own problem, but one thing i wanna ask, is it possible to have more columns in my $where variable?

Comment: @PotPot Well, you could do that by adding OR, so..

`$where .= "(studId LIKE '%$keyword%' OR fname LIKE '%$keyword%')";`

Comment: $EM-Creations... ah ok, now i could have my search box more  reliable... thnks a lot