# how to get the value of results in searchbox

Tags: php

this one is related to my other asked question 
"([get result on search box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14683856/get-result-on-search-box/14684518#14684518))"
from the search.php....i made some changes specifically on executing the result of search box, shown like this and this will execute a result in a checkbox form.

```
      foreach($results as $result) {

  echo "<input type = 'checkbox' name ='studid[]'          value='".$result['studId']." onchange='get_searched_value()''>";
   echo ' ', $result['fname'],'  ',$result['mname'],' ',$result['lname'],'<br/>';
        }
```

i made another form name regitercand.php and i just include the form search.php here.

```
<form method="post" name="searched" action="registercand.php">
                    <?php  require_once('search.php'); ?>
                    <input type="submit" name="select" value="Select">
                    </form>
//here i want to get the value of my search.php(foreach result) from the checked/selected result as i click the select button.. 
<?php
if(isset($_POST['select'])){
$studid = $_POST['studid'];
$position = $_POST['position'];
 echo $studid;
     echo $position;
}
echo "<table>";

echo "<tr><td>Running for:</td></tr><tr><td><select name='position'>
                <option value='0' style='font-size: 1em;'>---SELECT---</option>
                <option value='1'>Chairman</option>
                <option value='2'>Vice Chairman</option>
                <option value='3'>Secretary</option>
                <option value='4'>Treasurer</option>
                <option value='5'>Auditor</option>
                <option value='6'>Bus. Manager</option>
                <option value='7'>P.I.O</option>
                <option value='8'>Councilor</option>
                <option value='9'>CCEITE Representative</option>
                <option value='10'>CCJE Representative</option>
                <option value='11'>CAS Representative</option>
                <option value='12'>CTE Representative</option>
                <option value='13'>CBMA Representative</option></td></tr> ";
        $yrnw = date("Y");
        $lyr = 1;
        $lstyr = $yrnw - $lyr ;
        $sy = 10 + $yrnw;
    echo "<tr><td>SY:</td></tr><tr><td><select name= 'sy'>";              
             for($i=$yrnw; $i<$sy ; $i++){
            $lst = $i -1;
            echo "<option value='$i'>$lst-$i<br/></option>";
                       } 
echo "</select></td></tr>
    //here i put save button for another purpose, the result i selected from above will be save into my database. 
<tr><td><input type='button' name='save' value='Save'/></td></tr>
</table>
";
?>
```

the flow is like this. after executing all the results from my searchbox, i will check the names of student to select a candidate(2 or more) and click the select button, then the selected names will be set to select an option for his/her postion then click the save button to save in my table.
how would i possibly get the value of my checkbox & do the save button? plss help, & give me some advice....

Comment: @HydraIO. what do you mean i tried?

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem? input name="candidates[]" on each checkbox, then use $_REQUEST['candidates'] and it returns an array with all checked candidates

Comment: thnks William N. i change my codes and this is how it looks now if(isset($_POST['select'])){
 $studId = $_REQUEST['studid'];
 foreach ($studId as $ch){
 echo $ch."<br>";
 }
 }. now my problem is do the save button... can u help me again for that?

Comment: What do you need the save button to do exactly?

Comment: i want to save all the studid w/c are selected with the corresponding position and sy(school year) details. if you notice the above code, there is select option, that what its purpose... pls help me William N