# how to show/hide submit button on array checkbox

Tags: php

how can i apply this http://jsfiddle.net/8YBu5/24/ into my codes shown below. it hides only my submit button even the checkbox is checked or unchecked as the form load...

```
foreach($results as $result) {
<input type ='checkbox'  name ='studid[]' value='". $result['studId']."' id='checky' >
echo ' ', $result['fname'],'  ',$result['mname'],' ',$result['lname'],'<br/>';
}
        <input type="submit" name="select"  value="Select" id='postme' >
```

Comment: Please be more specific about your question ?

Comment: @DevangRathod.. i want to hide my submit button if the checkbox is uncheck and show if it is checked.

Comment: what bt terms and conditions...you want to hide it too??

Comment: @SankalpMishra. mine here is totally diffrnt from terms & cond. this one is a result from my searchbox, it is related from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14683856/get-result-on-search-box/14684518#14684518 (search.php). it could have 2 or more results search from my database in a checkbox form. now i what i want is to hide my submit button if theres no checkbox selected and show if there is..

Comment: $('#checky').click(function(){
    if(checky.checked == false) {
           $('#postme').toggle();;
    }
});

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($results as $result) {
<input type ='checkbox'  name ='studid[]' value='". $result['studId']."' class='checky' >
echo ' ', $result['fname'],'  ',$result['mname'],' ',$result['lname'],'<br/>';
}
        <input type="submit" name="select"  value="Select" id='postme' >
```

and

```
$('.checky').click(function(){
   $('#postme').toggle();
});
```

This is only to select all your checkboxes, and not only one. There sould not be id duplicates in a HTML page.

But this code is dumb.

Comment: it still hide my button..  why is it?

Comment: so you mean that if i had 10 checkboxes then i will check only 5, it will not work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.checky').click(function()
   {
        if($(".checky:checked").length == 0) {
            $('#postme').hide();
        } else {
            $('#postme').show();
        }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

your html

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checky"><a id="link" href="#">terms and conditions</a>
<input type="submit" id="postme" value="submit">
```

Now jQuery

```
$('#checky').click(function(){
   $('#postme').toggle();
    if(checky.checked == false) {
        $('#link').hide();
    } else {
        $('#link').show();
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
#postme{ display: none; }
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/8YBu5/24/